# Parsing an escape character

Tags: python, parsing

Using Python, I'm trying to parse a string like this:

```
"hello" "I am an example" "the man said:\"hello!\""
```

into these tokens:

```
1) hello
2) I am an example
3) the man said: "hello!"
```

Something like `re.findall(r'"[^"]*"', str)` comes close, but cannot handle the escape char (\). I'm curious what kind of pythonic ways there are to deal with the escape char without resorting to for loops or large parser packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good fit for regex:

```
re.findall(r'"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"', str)
```

**Explanation:**

```
"        # Match a "
(?:      # Match either...
 \\.     # an escaped character (\\, \" etc.)
|        # or
 [^"\\]  # any character except " or \
)*       # any number of times
"        # Match a "
```

This will correctly handle escaped backslashes:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = r'"hello" "Hello\\" "I am an example" "the man said:\"hello!\\\""'
>>> for match in re.findall(r'"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"', test):
...     print(match)
...
"hello"
"Hello\\"
"I am an example"
"the man said:\"hello!\\\""
```

Comment: You're regex is correct and very useful thank you! But your example is actually not correct, since it will not return `"Hello\\"` as a token, but rather `"Hello\\" "` (as it should). I'm picking you as my favorite answer, because it does not rely on a tokenizer package.

Comment: @Rodin: My example string was meant as a raw string; I have added actual code to make this clearer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a Python tokenizer:

```
import StringIO
s = r'"hello" "I am an example" "the man said:\"hello!\""'
sio = StringIO.StringIO(s)
t = list(tokenize.generate_tokens(sio.readline))
for tok in t: 
    print tok[1]
```

prints:

```
"hello"
"I am an example"
"the man said:\"hello!\""
```

This assumes that you really want Python syntax for your strings.

Comment: actually, I only wanted to handle the \" case. But thank you for pointing out the tokenizer package.

Answer (score -1):

You could replace the '\' tokens in the original string before `re`xing them:

```
input_string = '"hello" "I am an example" "the man said:\"hello!\""'
input_string.replace('\', '')
```

**EDIT:** I'm not sure if you have to escape the '\' sign. maybe you have to write:

```
input_string.replace('\\', '')
```

Comment: Great. Now his problem has become impossible to solve because you can't differentiate between normal quotes and escaped quotes any longer.